# Why does Future.onSuccess not fail the future?

Tags: scala, future

Suppose, I want to do some validation of the result after the future completes:

```
 def futureUser() {
   val foo = Future(getUserData(userId))
   foo.onSuccess { 
     case None => throw new InvalidUserId(userId)
   }
   foo // This sucks too btw: why doesn't `onSuccess` return `this` ???
 }
```

This does not do what it seems like it would at all: `futureUser` returns a successful `Future` of `None`, and the exception is dumped to the console and "swallen". 
It looks like this is actually done on purpose (twitter futures behave the same way ... except, at least, `.onSuccess` is "chainable"). Why? What's the reason for this?

**UPDATE** Ok, I need to mention, that `Option` is used here only for the sake of example. Consider this instead:

```
def futureItems() = Future(getInterestingItems()).map { 
    case Nil => throw new NothingInterestingFound()
    case bar => bar // <-- this is the ugly piece that I could avoid if .onSuccess did not swallow failures
  }
```

Comment: It's just the way the API is designed. `onSuccess` is for people who want to think / work in terms of callbacks and side effects. If you want nice compositional combinators there are plenty of those as well.

Comment: @TravisBrown well, that's the problem, there doesn't actually seem to be any "nice combinators" available for my use case, other than the quite ugly `foo.map { case None => throw ... ; case x => x }` :( Have I missed any?

Comment: @TravisBrown @Dima doesn't ScalaZ's `Task` behave the way you want?

Comment: @Dima Why not just `flatMap` and `Future.failed`? Generally in a situation like that I'd want to get rid of the `Option` in the result, anyway.

Comment: @TravisBrown, the `Option` is only here for the sake of example. In real life there are other possibilities. A `List` for instance (see my updated question).

Answer (score 0):

How about writing this as:

```
foo map { _.getOrElse(throw new Exception()) }
```

As stated in comments, `onSuccess` is only useful if you don't care about the result (only side-effects are important).

For example, you could do some logging in `onSuccess`. Sending an email does also make sense (you want to send it when something succeeds but you don't need to wait for sending to finish).

Comment: that works for `Option`, but how about other result types? For example, throw if a `List` is empty? (See updated question),

Comment: I think `filter` should do the trick: `foo filter { _.nonEmpty }`. However, if the list is empty, `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown, see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/concurrent/Future.html.

Comment: exactly. I need to return an application specific exception, describing the error condition. You are reading too much into the examples I provide. The actual real life validation is not as primitive as this.

Comment: How about: `foo filter { _.nonEmpty } recover { throw new AppSpecificException() }`. Not sure if it's more elegant than your `map`, though...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just do validation on a successful `Future` then you just want `transform`:

```
Future(getInterestingItems()).transform(validate, identity)
```

which can even be sugared nicely:

```
implicit class FutureFailureTransform[T](private val f: Future[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def validated(isValid: T => T): Future[T] = {
    f.transform(isValid, identity)
  }
}

// Use
Future(getInterestingItems()).validated {
  case Nil => throw new NothingInterestingFound()
}
```

Alternatively, if you were fine with the `NoSuchElementException` you could use [`Future.collect`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/#scala.concurrent.Future):

```
Future(getInterestingItems()) collect {
  case InterestingCase(data) => // Do stuff here
}
```

> If the current future contains a value for which the partial function is defined, the new future will also hold that value. Otherwise, the resulting future will fail with a `NoSuchElementException`.
>
> If the current future fails, then the resulting future also fails.

And if you needed a different exception, you would just chain the `collect` with a `transform`:

```
transform(identity, _ => new NothingInterestingFound())
```

Comment: The OP seems to want identity for values that aren't matched, which is the opposite of what `collect` does.

Comment: If you want a different exception just use `transform(identity, YourFailureConstructor(_))` ... right?

Comment: @TravisBrown ah, exactly, I missed that. `.filter`, like the other answer suggests would work, but I'd be stuck with `NoSuchElementException` with a cryptic (from the downstream user standpoint) message "predicate is not satisfied" ...

Comment: @SeanVieira `transform` works, but that looks even uglier than my solution with `.map` :)

Comment: @Dima - updated with a (hopefully) prettier solution.